# Importing a Youtrack 5 database into Youtrack 6

Tags: youtrack

I currently have a stand alone instance of Youtrack 6 installed from the ZIP distribution.

When I try to import the database from the Youtrack 5 instance into Youtrack 6, Youtrack 6 starts up using the host and port of Youtrack 5, which is a WAR file running on Tomcat.

ie. My Youtrack 5 instance could be access at `<server>:8080/youtrack`, and I setup my Youtrack 6 instance to run on `<server>:8081`. After importing the database, all visits to `<server>:8081` is immediately directed to `<server>:8080/youtrack`.

I followed these [steps](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD4/Restoring+Database+from+a+Backup) to import the database from Youtrack 5 to Youtrack 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database left baseURL without changes. Please, restart YouTrack 6 instance with following parameter:
jetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl

Refer to https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Providing+Java+Start+Parameters to learn how to provide Java parameters directly for ZIP and MSI distributives.